# Trazer determinado campo, pelo MAX(ID)

Tags: sql-server

Como eu faço para trazer um campo qualquer, pelo maior ID da tabela. Fiz um MAX(Campo1), Campo2 e tive que fazer um agrupamento pelo Campo2 e o resultado ele me trouxe vários Campo2 e não apena um, que tenha o maior ID.

```
Select MAX(ID), campo2 from tabela where campo3 = valor group by campo2
```

Isso não deu certo, me trouxe vários campo2

Comment: Você quer obter um determinado campo do registo com o maior ID?

Answer (score 2):

Se você quer simplesmente trazer o maior Id da tabela, apenas isso resolve:

```
Select MAX(ID) from tabela;
```

Afinal, Id é único e não precisa agrupar valores.

Se você precisa trazer outro campo baseado no `MAX(ID)`, o correto é:

```
select campo2
from tabela
where ID = (select MAX(ID) from tabela);
```

Comment: Sim, mas eu preciso trazer o outro campo por esse id max. Preciso do campo2 em realidade, baseado nesse MAX(ID), como eu faço isso?

Comment: @pnet Atualizei a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Assim resolveu, mas tive que colocar uma subquery na jogada

```
select campo2 from tabela where campo3= 49 and campo1  in (select max(campo1) from tabela where campo3 = 49)
```

Aí resolveu.